# using fread to read into int buffer

Tags: c++, c, buffer, fread

I would like to know if I can use fread to read data into an integer buffer. 
I see fread() takes void * as the first parameter. So can't I just pass an integer
buffer (typecast to void *) and then use this to read howmuchevery bytes I want to from the file, as long as the buffer is big enough ?

ie. cant i do:

```
  int buffer[10];
  fread((void *)buffer, sizeof(int), 10, somefile);
  // print contents of buffer
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  cout << buffer[i] << endl;
```

What is wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try it? What is the behavior you see?

Comment: yes. I did. I tried lot of different things ! but all the time, some big integers are printed that are not there in the file ! they dont look like addresses also. Numbers like: 889860408
906639670
822751544
170997553
875901745
875704842
909249077
839530032

Comment: The code provided is valid. However, additional checks for fread should be done. Moreover, the problem is probably in what data you actually have in the file.

Answer (score 7):

This should work if you wrote the ints to the file using something like `fwrite` ("binary" write). If the file is human-readable (you can open it with a text editor and see numbers that make sense) you probably want `fscanf` / `cin`.

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned fread should be able to do what you want
provided the input is in the binary format you expect. One caveat
I would add is that the code will have platform dependencies and
will not function correctly if the input file is moved between
platforms with differently sized integers or different
endian-nesses (sp).

Also, you should always check your return values; fread could fail.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use fread to read into an array of integers

```
int buffer[10]; 

size_t readElements = fread((void *)buffer, sizeof(int), 10, somefile); 

for(int i = 0; i < readElements; i++) 
   cout << buffer[i] << endl
```

You can check the number of elements fread returns to print out.

EDIT: provided you are reading from a file in binary mode and the values were written as cnicutar mentioned with fwrite.

Comment: No. It still prints weird numbers. That are not there in the file !

Answer (score 2):

I was trying the same and was getting the same result as yours, large int value when trying to read integer using `fread()` from a file and finally got the reason for it.
So suppose if your input file contains only:

1. "`5`"
2. "`5 5 5`"

The details I got from http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/beginnercpp/396198/396198/fread-returns-invalid-integer/

`fread()` reads binary data (even if the file is opened in 'text'-mode). The number `540352565` in hex is `0x20352035`, the `0x20` is the ASCII code of a space and `0x35` is the ASCII code of a `'5'` (they are in reversed order because using a little-endian machine).

So what `fread` does is read the ASCII codes from the file and builds an int from it, expecting binary data. This should explain the behavior when reading the `'5 5 5'` file. The same happens when reading the file with a single `'5'`, but only one byte can be read (or two if it is followed by a newline) and `fread` should fail if it reads less than `sizeof(int)` bytes, which is `4` (in this case).

Comment: More or less...`fread()` reads the bytes (which need not be ASCII codes since ASCII was a 7-bit system and bytes are normally (essentially always) 8-bit quantities).  And then, when those bytes are interpreted as an integer, you get the result you describe (on a little-endian machine).  If the binary data was not written with `fwrite()` on a machine sufficiently similar to the one you read the data on, there's no reason to suppose `fread()` will make sense of the data.

Answer (score 1):

As the reaction to response is that it still does not work, I will provide here complete code, so you can try it out.

Please note that following code does NOT contain proper checks, and CAN crash if file does not exist, there is no memory left, no rights, etc.
In code should be added check for each open, close, read, write operations.

Moreover, I would allocate the buffer dynamically.

```
int* buffer = new int[10];
```

That is because I do not feel good when normal array is taken as pointer. But whatever. Please also note, that using correct type (uint32_t, 16, 8, int, short...) should be done to save space, according to number range.

Following code will create file and write there correct data that you can then read.

```
    FILE* somefile;
    somefile = fopen("/root/Desktop/CAH/scripts/cryptor C++/OUT/TOCRYPT/wee", "wb");

  int buffer[10];
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    buffer[i] = 15;

  fwrite((void *)buffer, sizeof(int), 10, somefile);
  // print contents of buffer
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  cout << buffer[i] << endl;

  fclose(somefile);

    somefile = fopen("/root/Desktop/CAH/scripts/cryptor C++/OUT/TOCRYPT/wee", "rb");

  fread((void *)buffer, sizeof(int), 10, somefile);
  // print contents of buffer
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  cout << buffer[i] << endl;

  fclose(somefile);
```