# Is there any way to split a number with multiplication of some prime number

Tags: algorithm, primes

I am looking for an algorithm which help me to split a number **N** as like that
N = (p<sub>1</sub><sup>a</sup>)*(p<sub>2</sub><sup>b</sup>)*.....*(p<sub>n</sub><sup>z</sup>)

where

```
N is the given number
p is prime numbers smallest to greatest
a,b,..z are the power over the prime
* is the multiplication operation
```

Comment: What have you tried? I guess you will soon get a downvote coming to your question.

Comment: This a question to be moved to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @LuisAndrésGarcía: This question is about an algorithm.  It's relevant for SO.

Comment: I already replied to a similar question. You even have the C code : [Optimizing I/O(Output) in C code + a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945431/optimizing-i-ooutput-in-c-code-a-loop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called **factorization**. Keywords to google: `prime factorization algorithm`.

The problem is, that we still are not able to do this really fast. It makes quite a good base for cryptography (e.g. RSA algorithm).

Good luck!

Comment: "not able to do this really fast" means algorithm is `O(NlogN)` which is fine for reasonable value of `N`. Just that in the world of cryptography, `O(N)` by itself is terrible...

Comment: Indeed it does; the OP didn't tell us anything about numbers he was trying to factorize, so.. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a so complex problem if we do not care about the time optimization! Below is the simple code that works.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<map>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int get_primes(int max_number, vector<int> &primes)
{
    int *table = new int[max_number + 1];

    memset(table, -1, sizeof(int) * (max_number + 1));

    table[0] = table[1] = 0;

    primes.clear();

    for(int i = 2;i<=max_number ;i++)
    {
        if(table[i])
        {
            primes.push_back(i);
            for(int j = i * i;j<=max_number;j+=i)
            {
                table[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    delete [] table;
    return primes.size();
}

int get_prime_factor(int number, map<int , int> &factors)
{
    vector<int> primes;
    get_primes(number,primes);

    factors.clear(); 
    int ret = 0;
    for(int i = 0;primes[i] <= number;)
    {
        if(number % primes[i] == 0)
        {
            ret ++;
            factors[primes[i]] ++;
            number /= primes[i];
        }
        else
            i++;
    } 
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"Please input a number:"<<endl;
    int number;

    cin>>number;

     map<int , int> factors;
     get_prime_factor(number,factors);


    for(map<int,int>::iterator itr= factors.begin();itr != factors.end();++itr)
    {
            cout<<"("<<itr->first<<"**"<<itr->second<<")";
    }

    cout<<endl;
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;

}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are many algorithms for factoring an integer: trial division, Pollard's rho algorithm, elliptic curves, quadratic sieve, and others. Googling for some of those topics will help. To get you started, here is an algorithm for factoring by trial division:

```
function td_factors(n)
    f = 2
    while f * f <= n
        if n % f == 0
            output f
            n /= f
        else
            f = f + 1
    output n
```

For further reading, I modestly recommend the [essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) on my blog.