# Summation of all proper divisors

Tags: c, performance

I have solved a question that says:
Given a natural number n (1 <= n <= 500000), please output the summation of all its proper divisors.

Definition: A proper divisor of a natural number is the divisor that is strictly less than the number.

e.g. number 20 has 5 proper divisors: 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, and the divisor summation is: 1 + 2 + 4 + 5 + 10 = 22.

Input

> An integer stating the number of test cases (equal to about 200000), and that many lines follow, each containing one integer between 1 and 500000 inclusive.

Output

> One integer each line: the divisor summation of the integer given respectively.

Example

Sample Input:

> 3
>   2
>   10
>   20

Sample Output:

> 1
>   8
>   22

My code is as follows:

```
/* @BEGIN_OF_SOURCE_CODE */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {
        int sum = 0,
        cases = 0,
        i, j, buff;

        scanf("%d", &cases); //Number of tests


        int *n;
        n = (int*) malloc(cases * sizeof(int)); //Defining array for numbers to be tested///////

        for (i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &n[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < cases; i++ ) {
            buff = n[i] / 2;
            if (n[i] == 1) {
                sum = -1;
            }


            if (!(n[i] & 1)) {
                for (j = 2; j < buff; j++) {
                    if (n[i] % j == 0) {
                        sum += n[i] / j + j;
                        buff /= j;
                    }
                }
            }


            else {
                for (j = 3; j < buff; j += 2) {
                    if (n[i] % j == 0) {
                        if (n[i] / j == j) { sum += j; break; }
                        else sum += n[i] / j + j;
                    }
                    buff /= j;
                }
             }
            printf("%d\n", ++sum);
            sum = 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    /* @END_OF_SOURCE_CODE */
```

but it is not fast enough. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think this code is from *Chef Code*.

Comment: why are you mallocing?

Comment: And what are you expecting to do for double-factors (e.g. 4 has a factor of 2 twice)?

Comment: Also, you're not freeing the memory you allocated with `malloc`.

Comment: This code is C code.

I did it without malloc first, but then used malloc for no reason.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to codereview SE site.

Comment: @OrkhanHasanli You should not use `malloc()` if it's not explicitly necessary.

Comment: Zac, I fixed that before, but copied my code from wrong source, sorry for that. The problem is with its speed. I need just suggestions how to make it faster

Comment: I will not, I didn't use it before, but it didn't work either

Comment: smells like SPOJ to me.

Answer (score 7):

I have updated the code below to terminate sooner.  Running it for all integers from 1 to 500,000 takes under half a second on a MacBookPro6,1 (2.66 GHz Intel Core i7), compiled with Apple GCC 4.2.1 with -O3.

It uses the formula for σ<sub>x</sub>(*n*) in the Properties section of the [Wikipedia page for the divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Properties). It could be made faster with a list of precalculated primes. (126 are needed to support inputs up to 500,000, and this reduces the time to less than a quarter of a second.) There are also some divisions that can be eliminated, at the expense of cluttering the code slightly.

```
//  Return the least power of a that does not divide x.
static unsigned int LeastPower(unsigned int a, unsigned int x)
{
    unsigned int b = a;
    while (x % b == 0)
        b *= a;
    return b;
}


//  Return the sum of the proper divisors of x.
static unsigned int SumDivisors(unsigned int x)
{
    unsigned int t = x;
    unsigned int result = 1;

    //  Handle two specially.
    {
        unsigned int p = LeastPower(2, t);
        result *= p-1;
        t /= p/2;
    }

    //  Handle odd factors.
    for (unsigned int i = 3; i*i <= t; i += 2)
    {
        unsigned int p = LeastPower(i, t);
        result *= (p-1) / (i-1);
        t /= p/i;
    }

    //  At this point, t must be one or prime.
    if (1 < t)
        result *= 1+t;

    return result - x;
}
```

Comment: I see, you take a short cut to computing the sum by computing (pow(p, k+1)-1)/(p - 1).

Comment: I think if you modify the `LeastPower()` function to divide out the prime powers as you go, you will get a speed up because the `%` operator result will get reused by the subsequent divide, so the divide is free.

Comment: @jxh: Thanks, that is useful. I had already reduced the time to .061 seconds with some other modifications, including memoization. Your change brings it to .027 seconds (for finding the sums of divisors of all numbers from 1 to 500,000).

Comment: Wow, memoization is a massive win.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to allocate space. Just do line by line.
For each line, there is an O( n ^ 1/2 ) algorithm.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::cin;

int main() {
   int count, number;
   cin >> count;
   for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
      cin >> number;
      int sum = 1;
      for ( int j = 2; j * j <= number; ++j ) {
         if ( number % j == 0 ) {
            sum += j;
            sum += number / j;
         }
         if ( j * j == number ) sum -= j; // recalculate twice
      }
      cout << sum << endl;
   }
}
```

This is the runtime for 200,000 test case

```
real    0m55.420s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m16.124s
```

Comment: It is not optimized well. Cause for odd numbers you are checking whether it is divisable by even number or not. My code works fine. I dont have any error. Just need to make it faster.

Comment: Just for your sake, I submitted your code. It does not work and it is slower than my code.

Comment: btw, How do you check the runtime?

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"? Doesn't complied? Run time error?

Comment: 55 seconds on what system? The code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18836978/298225) computes the sums of the divisors of all the integers from 1 to 500,000 in less than half a second on a Mac Pro with a 2.66 GHz Intel Core i7.

Comment: Not only compute, I print to screen, it took a lot of time. Virtural machine with i7 and 4GB RAM I run it only for compute, less than half second too.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `user    0m0.016s` is the time this program spent on actual computation.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Something is missing. First, we were not given the input for the “200,000 test case”; the actual input is held by Code Chef. Second, when I pass the program “200000” followed by the integers from 1 to 200000, it takes .428 seconds of user time, also on a Core i7, but real, not virtual. And it completes in one second of real time, not 55 (writing to a Terminal window on Mac OS X, faster to a file). Perhaps the virtual machine is not returning correct times.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by NOT storing the numbers in an array at all. You don't need to - just read the value, process it, and output the result. The compiler may well not realize that `n[i]` is the same value throughout the loop, and that nothing else modifies it.

The logic doesn't seem very clear to me. And `if (n[i] == 1) { sum = 1} else ...` would make more sense than setting `sum = -1`.

You could perhaps also, keep a list of "common factors" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), so that you don't have to recalculate the same thing many times over. [If you know that somehing has the factor 24, then it also has 2, 3, 4, 6 and 8, for example.

Comment: First parameter is "cases", let say it is 2. Then I have to input 2 numbers each in new line. Let say first one is 15. When I submit the input, it returns me a value before second input. So, I have to save them first, then do my dirty stuff. Moreover, I'm trying to return the value at the end, so assignment sum = -1 is just the way i use. I do not need stylish things, guys, all I need a suggestion for faster code.

Comment: My `if (n[i] == 1)` makes it faster by not doing the whole divide stuff - albeit it obviously doesn't matter. Why can't you output the value as you calculate it? Surely the code runs as `myprog < input.txt > result.txt`, so outputting the data as you calculate would work just fine...

Comment: Also, not using an array will (most likely) make it faster.

Comment: Believe in me, I DID ALL THINGS YOU SAID! None works. The error I get from submission is Time limit exceeded.

Comment: Then you are using the wrong method to solve the problem - I suspect jxh's solution is the one that is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

[I replied to a similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945431/optimizing-i-ooutput-in-c-code-a-loop/9951376#9951376)

There is a faster performing algorithm which is based on a [formula for the sum of divisor](http://planetmath.org/FormulaForSumOfDivisors) using the decomposition in prime factors.

First you construct a primetable such that the last prime squared is smaller than the upper bound for your number. Then you apply the formula to each entry. If a number is written as

```
n = a1^p1 * a1^p2 *... *an^pn
```

the complexity of finding the sum for a given number `n` will be

```
p1+p2+...+pn = roughtly log(n)
```

which is better than the complexity `O(sqrt(n))` of the first optimization which stop the loop early

Comment: hint: you can compute the primes with a program, print them, store them in a statis array (primetable={2,3,5,7...) and use them in the program to submit to the online judge. Which means zero time spent by the online judge in the prime factorization...

Comment: Given a natural number n (1 <= n <= 500000), please output the summation of all its proper divisors.
An integer stating the number of test cases (equal to about 200000)
Are you sure? There is time, memory limitations.

Comment: My bad I meant prime generation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a way to compute primes relatively quickly. This could be a one time upfront activity, bounded by the square root of the largest input value. In this case, you already know the bound of the largest input value (500000), so you can simply hard code a table of primes into the program.

```
static unsigned P[] = {
2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71,
73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151,
157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233,
239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317,
331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419,
421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503,
509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607,
613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701
};

static int P_COUNT = sizeof(P)/sizeof(*P);
```

Now, from the primes, for each input value, you can:

- Compute the prime factorization
- Compute the product of the sums of the powers of each prime factor.

This will result in the sum of the divisors. Subtract the input value from the sum to obtain the sum of proper divisors. These two steps can be combined into a single loop.

This algorithm works because multiplying polynomials naturally results in sums of all combinations of the polynomial terms multiplied together. In the case where each polynomial term consists of powers of primes that divide the input, the combinations of the terms multiplied together make up the divisors. The algorithm is fast, and should be able to process 500000 numbers in the interval [1, 500000] in less than a second on a Core i3 or better processor.

The following function implements the method described above.

```
unsigned compute (unsigned n) {
    unsigned sum = 1;
    unsigned x = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < P_COUNT; ++i) {
        if (P[i] > x / P[i]) break;    /* remaining primes won't divide x */
        if (x % P[i] == 0) {           /* P[i] is a divisor of n */
            unsigned sub = P[i] + 1;   /* add in power of P[i] */
            x /= P[i];                 /* reduce x by P[i] */
            while (x % P[i] == 0) {    /* while P[i] still divides x */
                x /= P[i];             /* reduce x */
                sub = sub * P[i] + 1;  /* add by another power of P[i] */
            }
            sum *= sub;                /* product of sums */
        }
    }
    if (x > 1) sum *= x + 1;           /* if x > 1, then x is prime */
    return sum - n;
}
```

Comment: A version of the above program running on all numbers from 1 to 500000 (in random order) on [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/qaD9HU).

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of this code in O(n * log(n)). But you can output the required answer with constant time.

```
int ans[500000 + 10], m = 500000;

int f(){
    for(int i = 1; i <= m; i++){
       for(int j = i + i; j <= m; j += i){
           ans[j] += i;
       }
     }
}
```

Here ***ans*** is an array that contain sum of proper divisor from 2 to m.