# How to do the sum up of divisor of the input number?

Tags: c, for-loop, sum, perfect-numbers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#pragma warning (disable:4996)

int main() {
    int input,divisor, sum;

    printf("Input the number:");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    printf("\nThe positive divisor:");

    for (int i = 1; i <input; i++)
    {
        if (input%i==0)
        {
            printf("%d\t", i);//possible divisor of input number
            
        }
    }
    
    printf("\nThe sum of the divisor is:%d", &sum);<---how to sum up all the divisor number?

    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oflkr.png)

I've been trying to do the sum up, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: `sum += i`? And don't print the pointer to `sum`.

Comment: "I couldn't figure it out." is insufficient.  After enabling all compiler warnings, what compiler warnings were received?  What input was used, What output was seen? What was expected?

Comment: [Relevant.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836303/summation-of-all-proper-divisors)

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation**

Hi, in this case, you would not need to use the pointer for *"sum"*. First of all, you gotta initialize your *"sum"* variable to 0. Then, in the *"for"* loop, add the *"i"* into *"sum"*.

**Code (C/C++)**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#pragma warning (disable:4996)
int main() { 
    int input = 0;
    int divisor = 0;
    long long int sum = 0;      // This has to be initialized first to 0, use a 
                                // long long to avoid possible overflow

    printf("Input the number:");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    printf("\nThe positive divisor:");

    if (input == 1)           // when input is 1, the sum should be value
         sum = 1;
    
    for (int i = 1; i <input; i++)
    {
        if (input%i==0)
        {
            printf("%d\t", i);//possible divisor of input number
            sum += i;
        }
    }

    printf("\nThe sum of the divisor is:%d", sum); // print sum

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, @chux-ReinstateMonica, you are right, thanks for the reminder, I'll do the correction shortly

Comment: In the `input == 1`, I apologize. "sum of the divisor" seems to _not_ include `input`. So the output in cases of `input` of 1, 0, -1, -2, ... are not well defined.

Answer (score 2):

- Enable all compiler warnings
- Alternative algorithm

This is much faster than `for (int i = 1; i <input; i++)` as it only goes to the square root of `input` and well handles edge cases.

```
Pseudo code to allow OP the fun of coding up a better solution.

Set sum to 0
Set divisor to 1
Iterate almost to the root of n
while (divisor < n/divisor) {
  if (input%divisor == 0)
    Add the divisor and n/divisor to the sum
  Increment divisor
Now try the square root
if (divisor == n/divisor) {
  Add the divisor to the sum
Print sum
```

Other improvements possible

- After finding a divisor, scale `n` down and try again.  Remember to scale up the other factor.
- Define what should happen with `input <= 1`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code I don't see sum variable initialized, You can define sum variable and initialize to 0 and then keep adding the number to sum

```
for (int i = 1; i <input; i++)
{
    if (input%i==0)
        {
            sum += i    
        }
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- the variable `sum` is not initialized, `divisor` is not used.
- you should add `i` to `sum` when you find a divisor: `sum = sum + i;` or `sum += i;`
- to print `sum`, pass its value `sum` rather than its address `&sum` to `printf`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#pragma warning (disable:4996)  // disable compiler warning on scanf

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int input, sum = 0;

    printf("Input the number:");
    if (scanf("%d", &input) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("\nThe positive divisors:");
    for (int i = 1; i <= input / i; i++) {
        if (input % i == 0) {
            int q = input / i;
            printf(" %d", i);
            sum += i;
            if (i != q && i != 1) {
                printf(" %d", q);
                sum += q;
            }
        }
    }
    
    printf("\nThe sum of divisors is: %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```