# Project Euler challenge 3: Finding the largest prime factor of a large number

Tags: c++, algorithm

Can't find the prime factor of 600851475143 for projecteuler. My code successfully computes the largest prime factor of the test number 13195 and every test number I throw at it, but somehow it degrades with the large prime number. Do you know why?

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <queue>  
using namespace std;
int split(int split);
int largestprimefactor(priority_queue<int> myints);
int main()
{
int response = 2;
do{
    priority_queue<int> myints;
    int number;
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;
    myints.push(number);
    int lcf = largestprimefactor(myints);
    cout << endl << "Largest prime factor is: " << lcf;
    cout << endl << "Again?(1 for yes 2 for no): ";
    cin >> response;
}while(response == 1);
}
uint64_t split(uint64_t split)
{
if(split%2 != 0)
{
    if((split/2))%2 == 0)
        for(uint64_t i = (split/2)-1; i>1; i=i-2)
            if(split%i == 0)
                return i;
    else
        for(uint64_t i = (split/2); i>1; i=i-2)
            if(split%i == 0)
                return i;
    return 1;
}
else
    return 2;
}
int largestprimefactor(priority_queue<int> myints)
{
// largestfactor holds the next number to be tested for primeness in the queue
do{
    int largestfactor = myints.top();
    myints.pop();
    //splat will hold the first factor split finds of the top item in the queue
    int splat = split(largestfactor);
    //if it holds a 1 then that means that there are no factors
    if(splat != 1 && largestfactor)
    {
        myints.push(splat);
        myints.push(largestfactor / splat);
    }
    else
        return largestfactor;   
}while(myints.top() > 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered that 600851475143 is too large to store in a 32 bit int?

Look into what your compiler provides for 64 bit integer types.

Comment: I tried it with longs and I got the same answer, my code spits out 2147483647 which has a remainder when divided by 600851475143 :(

Comment: @CodeManiak: What size are longs on your system? try long long, or uint64_t

Comment: My system is crunching the numbers still... I"ll let you know! I can hear the processor humming... or the hard drive. Which one hums? The fan probably. Maybe I should get up and make a sandwich... Geez I know what prime I'm using next time I use RSA!

Comment: There's no reason for a good solution to problem 3 not to run in under a second, even in a scripting language.  Maybe you should reconsider your approach (as per comments on other answer).

Comment: @CodeManiak have you change to long for "every" location, not just the beginning of the code?

Comment: yeah it was because I changed everything to uint64 out of desperation. When I changed only the necessary int it ran much faster :)

Answer (score 1):

I might not be able to help you optimize your code (I'm not sure what you do in `split`), but here's an idea.

By the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), each number has a unique factorization into a product of primes. This means we can take a number and successively divide it by its prime factors until we reach 1. The last prime factor is the answer.

Now, you need only check prime factors up to *sqrt(N)*. Note that this does not mean that the largest prime factor is less than *sqrt(N)*, but that if there is a prime factor greater than *sqrt(N)*, there is only one such prime factor.

This leads to the following O(sqrt(N)) algorithm:

```
long long largest_factor(long long number) {
    long long result = 0;
    for (long long i = 2; i * i <= number; ++i) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            result = i;
            while (number % i == 0)
                number /= i;
        }
    }
    if (number != 1)
        return number;
    return result;
}
```

Running this on 600851475143 gives me the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

`600851475143 >> 32` give 129, `600851475143 >> 64` give 3.10^-8. This number is too big to be represented as an int, but you can represent it with a 64 bit number as long long or a class designed to represent bigger integers.

Comment: no, because long long is smaller than 2^64.

Comment: 2^ 64 = 18446744073709551616 > 600851475143

Comment: so I slightly optimized the "split" algorithm, but do you see any other ways to optimize this? It's still running on my laptop. Maybe one of you with a fast computer can try to run this and find the answer? :)

Comment: @Толя ok you are correct. codemaniak the goal is for you to implement an efficient algorithm, that's the idead of project euler

Comment: I agree, do you see any issues with my algorithm, or ways to improve?

There might be an easier way to sieve through a numbers largest factors but my method was to just get rid of everything that is divisible by 2 and decrement by 2 starting at prime/2. Seems like thats the simplest and best method without implementing drastic measures. But whatever method I chose its drastically expensive because its been 20 minutes and I still don't have a number lol

Comment: compute factors using prime decomposition. I gave an answer on a similar question. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9945811/1122645. Btw this is a different question.

Comment: So you implement the sieve of erasthenos to generate a prime table and then use that? interesting.... more work to do obviously.

Comment: yes. if you know the prime factorization, you can compute the biggest divisor by removing the smallest term. 24 = (2^3) * 3, so you you know youu need to remove 2. btw make it nice, primes + factorization is recurring in project euler, you may want to reuse your code.

Comment: If you think you can wander into Project Euler problems and tick 'em off with O(n) brute-force algorithms and a few simple optimisations that just give you a faster O(n), you will not get far at all, even if you ignore the minute runtime (for some problems a brute force approach would need 100s-1000s years runtime, and some even cosmic timescales).  Learning to implement prime sieves is hardly "drastically measures"; it's an essential skill you absolutely must master if you're going to get anywhere with PE.

Comment: @timday: true that you will need to implement a sieve for Euler, but a sieve isn't needed for this problem. What is needed, though, is *some* non-stupid factorization algorithm. Trial division up the the square root is easily good enough for this number, then there are a few simple improvements on that to bring the runtime from a fraction of a second down to a small fraction of a second :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: ok, just looked back at my solutions to low-numbered PE problems from years ago.  They're even simpler than I remember; yes, sieving doesn't come in until a bit later.